# Xen open source import and export vm

Tags: backup, xen

I am using free *Xen 4.2.4-30.el6* on *centos 6.5*

create a vm using **`virt-install`**

I want to backup and restore virtual machines, but all tutorials talking about *citrix* and `xe` command

is there any way to import and export without *citrix* ?

Comment: I have the same problem, it's like sitting alone in a dark room when dealing with XEN, please help us!

Comment: Me too, I'm really interested in this. Are we working in the same project guys?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your VMs using `xm`, (see `xm(1)` and search `save` and `restore`); this interface is text-only. You can also install libvirt to manage your VMs; in this case you have both a text interface (`virsh`) and a remote GUI (`virt-manager`).